# Facing error (0 , (_wordwrap || _load_wordwrap(...)).default)(...)(...).trimStart is not a function on expo init

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am trying to create react native application with [Expo](https://expo.io/). As per react native official documentation, I have installed Node 8+ (v8.12.0) & expo-cli on my windows system and then run command `expo init AwesomeProject`. But its giving error as

```
(0 , (_wordwrap || _load_wordwrap(...)).default)(...)(...).trimStart is not a function
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

When I enable expo debug, its giving

```
TypeError: (0 , (_wordwrap || _load_wordwrap(...)).default)(...)(...).trimStart
is not a function
    at C:\expo-cli@2.11.6\src\commands\init.js:105:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at _callee$ (C:\expo-cli@2.11.6\src\commands\init.js:95:37)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\shubhamt1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\no
de_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\shubhamt1\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:296:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\shubhamt1\Ap
pData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime
.js:114:21)
    at step (C:\Users\shubhamt1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_m
odules\babel-runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
    at C:\Users\shubhamt1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules
\babel-runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:35:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new F (C:\Users\shubhamt1\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_
modules\core-js\library\modules\_export.js:36:28)
```

Please help on this. I am missing something ?

Comment: Downgrading version works. Now I'm using 2.11.6

Comment: Thanks.It worked for me too

Comment: Just tested with Node 8.11, yarn v1.12 and 2.11.3 as the poster below stated. 

I am not seeing the error in 2.11.3.

Comment: I updated nodejs version to most recent (10.15.2) and that fixed the issue for me for anyone that doesn't want to downgrade versions of expo

Answer (score 8):

What you have to do basically is to update the expo client to 2.6.11, and then [update the node.js](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/#winmac) to a version greater than 10.0 (10 or newer version) and [install git](https://git-scm.com/download). After that, run the command

`expo init <app-name>`

According to [Expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/introduction/installation/),

> You'll need to have Node.js (version 10 or newer) installed on your computer. Download the latest version of Node.js. Additionally, you'll need Git to create new projects with Expo CLI

See [Getting Started-React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) for a comprehensive guide.

Answer (score 3):

Downgrading to 2.11.6 doesn't work for me :

```
~/Projects/ReactNativeApp (master)
$ expo --version
2.11.6

~/Projects/ReactNativeApp (master)
$ expo init ReactNativeApp
[12:07:17] (0 , (_wordwrap || _load_wordwrap(...)).default)(...)(...).trimStart is not a function
[12:07:17] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

I have to downgrade to 2.11.3 in order to skip this error.

I have the same issue with 2.11.5 and 2.11.4.

**Upgrading to node.js 10+ fixed this issue.**

Comment: upgraing node to 10+ fixed the this issue for me

Answer (score 1):

use lower version of expo,i think new version is still in beta.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with nodejs version, you can install nvm and then update easly the node version, i updated to version 10.15 and it works:
[Installing NVM at ubuntu](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-nvm-node-version-manager-for-node-js-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/)